# Expresso store checkout process - shipping city and postal code validation (disallowed characters)

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

It looks like Expresso store during the checkout process allows to use disallowed characters in postal code and city fields for shipping. Also postal code allows to put only 2 characters when shorter in the world is 3 digits. It creates problems when UPS or FedEx modules are used for shipping calculation.

Any clue how to limit postal code when shipping is only in the States and validate city name if doesn't contains numbers etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that you can validate your fields. You could use HTML5 validators such as `number` for zip codes. Something along the lines of

```
<input type="number" name="billing_postcode" maxlength="5" minlength="5" >
```

Personally though I prefer using the [CodeIgniter Styled Validation Rules](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference):

```
{exp:store:checkout
 rules:billing_postcode="required|numeric|min_length[5]|max_length[5]"
 rules:billing_city="min_length[3]|alpha"
 rules:phone="numeric" {!-- this would be applied to both shipping and billing fields --}
}
```

(Store documentation on [Rules](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#rules_field_name_rule).)